# Is private within this context? Trying to overload << operator

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <cctype>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <list>
#include <limits>

class Song {
    friend std::ostream &os(std::ostream &os, const Song &s);
    std::string name;
    std::string artist;
    int rating;
public:
    Song() = default;
    Song(std::string name, std::string artist, int rating) 
        : name{name}, artist{artist}, rating{rating} {}
    std::string get_name() const {
        return name;
    }

    std::string get_artist() const {
        return artist;
    }

    int get_rating() const {
        return rating;
    }

    bool operator<(const Song &rhs) const {
        return this->name < rhs.name;
    }

    bool operator==(const Song &rhs) const {
        return this->name == rhs.name;
    }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Song &s){
    os << std::setw(20) << std::left << s.name
        << std::setw(30) << std::left << s.artist
        << std::setw(2) << std::left << s.rating;
        return os;
}
```

I am getting the error Song::name is private within this context, but I did not make it private. The std::stream &operator above me with the formatted output is the one I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator<<` is a regular function, and your overload is trying to use private members of the class.  In a class, the default access is `private`, if you want public access by default, you should use a `struct`.

There are two ways to solve your issue:

1.) Write your `operator<<` overload to only use public data/functions:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Song &s){
    os << std::setw(20) << std::left << s.get_name()
        << std::setw(30) << std::left << s.get_artist()
        << std::setw(2) << std::left << s.get_rating();
        return os;
}
```

2.) Declare `operator<<` as a friend function to allow it access to internals of the class.  It looks like you tried to do this, but you have a typo:

```
friend std::ostream &os(std::ostream &os, const Song &s);
```

This declares a friend member function in your called `os`, not the operator overload you want, which is:

```
class Song {
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Song &s)
    //...
};
```

The interesting part about having these types of errors is that declaring something to exist without a definition is OK in C++, as long as you don't use it.  This is a problem for typos (we all make them), but it can be a useful language feature too, as removing a definition and recompiling can tell you if and where a function is actually used.

Comment: Ah no wonder I just mistyped I do not know why I put os it was suppose to be operator thank you so much.

Comment: @pyj Sorry, I accidentally downvoted your answer (not sure how that happened...).  Please edit it so that I can reverse my vote.

Answer (score 2):

The default access specifier for classes is `private`, that is why your `name` member defined outside the `public` specifier is a private variable.

More [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access):

> A class defined with the keyword class has private access for its
>   members and its base classes by default. A class defined with the
>   keyword struct has public access for its members and its base classes
>   by default. A union has public access for its members by default.

As you can see, a `struct` on the other hand has a default `public` which is the only difference between the two.

Comment: How would I go about fixing this? I get it now, but I put back inside my class public member functions and its still not working.

Comment: I also want to keep it as a class and not a struct.

Comment: Just a note: the only difference between class and struct is the default access specifier. As you will learn shortly, I bet, you do want to have those member variables private and change them/access through getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways

- Using the accessors (getters) to access to your private datas

Your getters are : `get_name()`, `get_artist()` and `get_rating()`

Code :

```
 std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Song &s){
        os << std::setw(20) << std::left << s.get_name()
            << std::setw(30) << std::left << s.get_artist()
            << std::setw(2) << std::left << s.get_rating();
            return os;
    }
```

- Using the friend keyword, a friend function is a function that is given the same access as methods to private and protected data. A friend function is declared by the class that is granting access, so friend functions are part of the class interface, like methods, But ! It is recommended to use friend functions "moderaly", it other terms, use them just in case they are the unique issue, for example, it is not recommended to use these last ones as setters (to modify the instance).

Code:

```
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Song &s){
            os << std::setw(20) << std::left << s.name
                << std::setw(30) << std::left << s.artist
                << std::setw(2) << std::left << s.rating;
                return os;
        }
```